# independence between an event and a set of events

Tags: probability-theory

On a probability space, from Billingsley's Probability and Measure,

> a family of classes of events is said to be independent, if we
>   arbitrarily choose an event from each class in the family, and these
>   events are then independent.

According to the above definition, I deduce the following definition:

> An event $A$ is said to be independent of events $B_1, B_2,\dots ,
>  B_m$ if $A$ and $B_i$ are independent, $\forall i =1, \dots, m$.

However, I saw from someone's private note that

> An event $A$ is said to be independent of events $B_1, B_2,\dots ,
>  B_m$ if for evew subset $S$ of $\{1, 2,\dots ,m\}$,  $$ P[A |\cap_{i \in
>  S} B_i] = P[A]. $$

1. Are the two different definitions equivalent?

   In other words, is the following true:

   > $A$ and $B_i$ are independent, $\forall i =1, \dots, m$, if and only
   >   if for evew subset $S$ of $\{1, 2,\dots ,m\}$,  $ P[A |\cap_{i \in S}  B_i] = P[A]. $
2. I wonder how to define independence between an event and a set of
   events correctly?
3. Same questions when there are infinitely many events $B_i, i \in I$?
4. Added: What is the definition of independence of an event and a set
   of events in [Lovasz local lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma#Asymmetric_Lov.C3.A1sz_local_lemma)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are not equivalent (I suspect the first definition may have been meant for a more specific context.)

Easy counterexample are variables $B_1,B_2$ that independently take values $-1$ and $1$ with chance half and $A=B_1B_2$. Then $A$ is independent of $B_1$ and $B_2$ separately but is fully determined by the two of them.

Comment: +1, though your counter example is of random variables rather than events.

Comment: Thanks! +1. What is the definition of independence of an event and a set of events in [Lovasz local lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma#Asymmetric_Lov.C3.A1sz_local_lemma)?

Comment: @Tim, the second definition is standard and looking around seems to confirm that it is indeed the definition used in the Lovasz local lemma.

Comment: Thanks! WHat sources have you found?

Comment: http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~hungngo/classes/2011/Spring-694/lectures/lm.pdf was fairly explicit w.r.t. to independence.